# Extracting unique column combination and finding sum and count in R

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I have a flight database with 4 columns like shown below.

Original:

[image]

I want an output which gives rows based on unique combination of 3 col (origin/destination/Airline), sums the number of passengers for each unique combination and count the numbers of rows for each unique combination. The result would be something like this.

Output:

[image]

I am able to do 1 part of it using the `group_by` function

```
df %>% group_by(Origin, destination, carrier) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

How to include the sum of population?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Origin, Destination, Airline) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(count = n(), TotalPassengers = sum(Passengers))
# Groups:   Origin, Destination [2]
#  Origin Destination Airline count TotalPassengers
#  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>   <int>           <dbl>
#1 ABE    ATL         9A          2               3
#2 ABE    ATL         DL          1               5
#3 NYC    SFA         AA          3              21
#4 NYC    SFA         DL          1               5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Origin = rep(c("ABE", "NYC"), c(3, 4)),
      Destination = rep(c("ATL", "SFA"), c(3, 4)),
      Airline = c("9A", "9A", "DL", "AA", "AA", "AA", "DL"),
      Passengers = c(2, 1, 5, 4, 10, 7, 5))
```

Comment: @GreenFinance Well, I am getting the output as in your expected output

Comment: @GreenFinance if you have loaded `plyr`, `plyr::summarise` could have masked `dplyr::summarise` do `df1 %>%
   group_by(Origin, Destination, Airline) %>% dplyr::summarise(count = n(), TotalPassengers = sum(Passengers))`

Comment: yup, getting it now. i was doing a mistake. Thanks again

Comment: @GreenFinance its okay.  I was just saying because many people who are new to the site wouldn't care to give some points to the person who answer it.  Having said that, these points are meaningless and it have no revenue strutucre or anything as in youtube etc.  It is just a token of appreciation.